# Json when posted added slashed and not remove even after replaces

Tags: javascript, json

My actual json when creates is something like :

```
{"edmGridData":[{"messageId":"ID:414d51205553544d494c333420202020ba53565966061b29"},{"messageId":"ID:414d51205553544d494c333420202020ba535659663a1b29"}]}
```

But when I post same variable to post , it send data something like :

```
"{\"edmGridData\":[{\"messageId\":\"ID:414d51205553544d494c333420202020ba53565966061b29\"},{\"messageId\":\"ID:414d51205553544d494c333420202020ba535659663a1b29\"}]}"
```

Although, I have used **Replace**, Its giving same issue , Any other work around for this in Javascript / Jquery ?

Comment: Does your code `JSON.stringify` the object?

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: *"But when I post same variable to post , it send data something like :"* A) Show us the code that does that. B) "something like" is much too vague. It's either what you've shown, or you need to go back and ensure that it's what you've shown. *"Although, I have used Replace"* You shouldn't need to, but again, show the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is String format of you JSON. you have to parse your JSON before use:

```
var obj = JSON.parse("{\"edmGridData\":[{\"messageId\":\"ID:414d51205553544d494c333420202020ba53565966061b29\"},{\"messageId\":\"ID:414d51205553544d494c333420202020ba535659663a1b29\"}]}");
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp